# SignalR application security with client mobile apps

Tags: signalr

I am developing SignalR application and my client applications are mobile applications. ( Android and iOS).

Question -

CORS - Do I have to enable cross domain if all calls coming from mobile devices ?

Security - What is the best way to secure my SignalR application in this scenario. I already read about Signal Security here

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

But not sure which one to apply in my case where all the calls comes from mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to enable CORS unless the server handling SignalR is at a different URL than the webserver.

Regarding security, follow the advice in the SignalR documentation that you linked to.  Start by using SSL, and requiring authorization at the hub level.  Exactly which approach to take depends on your requirements.  For example, are you authenticating against a windows domain server, or a local database, or a 3rd party service like facebook or gmail?

A comprehensive example resource for authentication with SignalR is the JabbR project:

http://about.jabbr.net/

https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR

Comment: So do you mean the CORS is only applicable to browser clients ? and not .net client or mobile app clients ?

Comment: how would one go about implementing authentication against a database? Would you have any links ?